# How to send an email when a NodeJS script exits?

Tags: node.js, email, exit, nodemailer

I tried to catch the `exit` event and send an email, but the [docu](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) says:

> Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations.

Usually I use [Nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) to send emails, but Nodemailer does not support synchronous operations. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can use promise.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I don't get your point. How would promises help here?